# Eliptic curve subgroup order

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to solve the following but I don't understand some of the steps and how to proceed. I found similar questions on the internet saying the order is 6 but I want to understand why.

```
Given an elliptic curve E/Q  (Q are the rationals) E/Q = y^2  = x^3 + 1 
determine the subgroup generated by point <2,3> and its size.
```

thinking that P(2,3) and P(2,-3) would yield (3-3)(2-2)= 0 why is that not the case?

Comment: It is the case. Use sage `sage: E1 = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0,1])
sage: P1 = E1(2,3)
sage: P2 = E1(2,-3)
sage: P1 + P2
 (0 : 1 : 0)
`. The point `(0:1:0)` is the point at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elliptic curve group comes with [formulae for adding together points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Algebraic_interpretation) with different formulae for distinct points and doubling. In your example, we can hand calculate the formulae by hand. We begin with $(2,3)+(2,3)$ so we use the doubling formula. We calculate the slope
$$s=\frac{3x_P^2+a}{2y_P}=\frac{3\times 2^2+0}{2\times 3}=2$$
and use this to compute new $x$ and $y$ coordinates
$$x_R=s^2-2x_P=2^2-2\times 2=0;\quad\quad y_R=y_P+s(x_R-x_P)=3+2\times(0-2)=-1.$$
We change the sign on $y_R$ to complete the group law. Thus $2(2,3)=(0,1).$ Next we compute $(0,1)+(2,3)$ using the distinct points formula. Again, we start with the slope
$$s=\frac{y_P-y_Q}{x_P-x_Q}=\frac{1-3}{0-2}=1$$
and use this to compute new $x$ and $y$ coordinates
$$x_R=s^2-x_P-x_Q=1^2-0-2=-1;\quad\quad y_R=y_P+s(x_R-x_P)=1+1\times(-1-0)=0$$
Changing the sign on $y_R$ doesn't change it so that $3(2,3)=(-1,0)$.

Similarly, $(-1,0)+(2,3)=(0,-1)$ so that $4(2,3)=(0,-1)$ and $(0,-1)+(2,3)=(2,-3)$ so that $5(2,3)=(2,-3)$.

Lastly we note that our formulae do not return rational numbers in the case $x_P=x_Q$ and $y_P=-y_Q$. In this special case, we say that the points add up to the point at infinity which is the group identity. Thus $6(2,3)=\mathcal O$ and the element is of order6 and so the subgropu that it generates is also of order 6.